# Sumar valores en columnas

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy intentando sumar los valores de cada columna y añadirlo en la ultima fila, pero no veo que se actualice el contenido. 
La tabla la construyo de la siguiente forma:

```
   echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'></td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>1</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>3</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>4</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>5</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>6</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'></td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>2</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>2</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>2</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>2</td>";
    echo"<td data-field='count'>2</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

        echo '<tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td> 
                <td id="total">.</td> 
                <td id="total">.</td> 
                <td id="total">.</td> 
                <td id="total">.</td> 
                <td id="total">.</td> 
            </tr>
        </tfoot>';
```

y mi jquery lo cargo mediante un script con el siguiente contenido:

```
var total = 0;

$(data).each(function(i){
    total = total+ parseInt(data[i].cound);
});
$('#total').html(total);
```

Es posible usar la misma función para cada columna?

Comment: Si estas armando la tabla con PHP, por que estas sumando con Jquery ? .. No sería mas facil sumar en el mimo php y mostrar el resultado ?

Comment: @MauricioJavierBiott porque en un futuro cogeré datos de una BBDD y serán dinamicos

Comment: Es probable que debas diferenciar las funciones ya que en el jquery el $('#total') son todas las columnas del tfoot .

Comment: @MauricioJavierBiott aunque lo deje en una única td no me hace la suma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este ejemplo se especifica como: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/13/) 
Todos los créditos son del creador del archivo. 
Respuesta de [Aymen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802244/sum-total-for-column-in-jquery) stackoverflow en ingles.

Un saludo

```
 <table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>Watermelon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">2</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">2</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rowDataSd">1</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">5</td>
            <td class="rowDataSd">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
            <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
            <td class="totalCol">Total:</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
<script>
       var totals=[0,0,0];
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $dataRows=$("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

            $dataRows.each(function() {
                $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){        
                    totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
                });
            });
            $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
                $(this).html("total:"+totals[i]);
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: me ha servido. gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro una alternativa para ver si te es útil.

Tabla, en este caso en HTML pero puede ser tu tabla dinámica con PHP

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td >Columna  1</td>
        <td >Columna  2</td>
        <td>Columna 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1" >1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1" >1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1" >1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1" >1</td>
        <td class="col2">2</td>
        <td class="col3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="total_col_1" >.</td>
            <td class="total_col_2" >.</td>
            <td class="total_col_3">.</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

Fución Jquery separando las columnas y sus totales para luego ser sumarizadas.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var tot1 = 0;
    var tot2 = 0;
    var tot3 = 0;
    $('.col1').each(function(e){
        tot1 += parseInt($(this).html());
    });
    $('.col2').each(function(e){
        tot2 += parseInt($(this).html());
    });
    $('.col3').each(function(e){
        tot3 += parseInt($(this).html());
    });
    $('.total_col_1').html(tot1);
    $('.total_col_2').html(tot2);
    $('.total_col_3').html(tot3);
</script>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.